# How to copy a value to another cells using weeknumber in padas python dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, stock

Please refer below image. I am trying to create a new column (i.e., Expected_Open) in Pandas dataframe. This columns will fetch Open value for each Monday of a give week. Thanks for your help.

[image]

following if condition only returns data in row = "Monday", but I am not sure how to copy it to other weekdays:
`if (x['Weekday'] == "Monday") : return x['open']`

Comment: Like `df.loc[df['Weekday']=='Monday', 'Open']` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df['Expected_Open'] = df['Weeknumber'].map(dict(df.loc[df['Weekday'] == 'Monday', ['Weeknumber', 'Open']].to_numpy()))
```